# Logs not generating while doing DMS tasks

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, data-migration, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I need to migrate the on premise data to postgres,i am done with all connection and other things but when i have started the data migration task,**it is failing**.I can't even see what is happening. can anybody help how can generate the logs so that i can fix it.